# Question on BRN Shear

Tags: meteorology, mesoscale-meteorology

The BRN Shear, which is the denominator of the bulk Richardson number, a parameter used in severe weather forecasting ([described here](https://www.spc.noaa.gov/exper/soundings/help/shear.html)), is (from [Stull's Practical Meteorology](https://geo.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Meteorology_and_Climate_Science/Book%3A_Practical_Meteorology_(Stull)/14%3A_Thunderstorm_Fundamentals/14.04%3A_Section_5-)):

$$\mathrm{BRN\;Shear} = 0.5 \cdot (\Delta M)^2$$

With $\Delta M$ defined as:

$$\Delta M = [(\Delta U)^2 + (\Delta V)^2]^\frac{1}{2}$$

where

$$\Delta U = \overline{U} - U_{SL}\\
   \Delta V = \overline{V} - V_{SL}$$

($U$,$V$) are wind components from 0 to 6 km 'weighted' average/mean winds.

I would like to ask for some clarification on the $U_{SL}$ and $V_{SL}$ terms.  Are these "surface-level" wind components, listed as being from 0 to 0.5 km,  also required to be a weighted average from 0 to 500 m AGL? Or do I only need a 'single' 0.5 km wind acting as the proxy for surface-level winds?

Comment: Where does your idea for using 0 - 0.5 km come from?  (Not saying it's not true, I don't know BRN particularly, but for the question it kind of poofs out of nowhere!)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest. Thanks for the comment. It came from this reference https://www.spc.noaa.gov/exper/soundings/help/shear.html. Meanwhile, the whole equation is seen from here 
https://geo.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Meteorology_and_Climate_Science/Book%3A_Practical_Meteorology_(Stull)/14%3A_Thunderstorm_Fundamentals/14.04%3A_Section_5-

Comment: ok, good deal, I'll edit your question a bit.  But I'm confused what you're asking exactly, as your question "are these surface-level wind components are from 0 to 0.5 km and also being average out" has got some brokenness in the wording.  Can you reread that and see if you can write that better (or if not sure how to, perhaps you can try asking that sentence here in your native language if English isn't your native language)?

Comment: @JeopardyTempest Thanks. I already edited the question.

Comment: Ok, please make sure that my edit still captures your intent with the question?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a clear definition on which height you are supposed to use tbh. I find many different ways how people calculate the surface layer windshear. Probably people just use which values they have available. As a rule of thumb I would generally say dont use anything below 100 m because of the influence of the ground. Above 100 m things dont change that much anymore.